# Can I use git submodule to manage individual files as well as directories?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a complex repository where sometimes the logical boundaries between code segments crosses directory boundaries. Sometimes a single file in directory X really needs to go with files in directory Y.

E.g., pretend I have a central repo that looks like this:

```
a/foo
a/bar
b/baz1
b/baz2
```

...and I want my local repository to end up with `a/*` and `b/baz1`, but not `b/baz2`.

(Yes, the long term solution is to move the files, but while I am working on that refactoring, I need to version-control the files appropriately.)

Can I use git submodule to work on a set of code that includes some directories and some other random files? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Git "submodule" feature is limited to subdirectories and all the files they contain.

Comment: This is fairly obvious when you consider the implementation: a submodule is a Git repository, meaning it contains a .git directory, so it'd better be a directory itself.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question to describe what you actually want to do, and see whether anybody can come up with a solution. This question has little about your actual problem, but only asks about a specific solution (which unfortunately doesn't seem to work in your case).

Comment: @Greg, asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741661/how-can-i-manage-overlapping-repositories-in-git-including-files-in-the-same-dir

Comment: it may not be what gists where intended for, but i successfully added a gist as a submodule. in one of my projects. no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Gists act as mini repositories and even include revision history. You can put your single files on gist.github.com and add them as submodules.

Even if hidden gists are public -- it's important to keep that in mind. Using gists may not be appropriate in all situations.