# How can I manage overlapping repositories in git, including files in the same directory?

Tags: git

I have a complex repository where sometimes the logical boundaries between code segments crosses directory boundaries. Sometimes a single file in directory X really needs to go with files in directory Y.

E.g., pretend I have a central repo that looks like this:

```
a/foo
a/bar
b/baz1
b/baz2
```

...and I want my local repository to end up with `a/*` and `b/baz1`, but not `b/baz2`. The other files should end up in another repository.

(Yes, the long term solution is to move the files, but while I am working on that refactoring, I need to version-control the files appropriately.)

Can I use git to do this?

Comment: This is what branches are for :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Git's [sparse checkout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) feature (if that link still doesn't work, try [this one](http://man.he.net/man1/git-read-tree) or see `man git-read-tree`). Run the following commands in your cloned repository:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo '*' >.git/info/sparse-checkout
echo '!b/baz2' >>.git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
```

This will delete the existing `b/baz2` file from your local working directory. It's still in the repository, but your local Git will not care about the fact that it's gone from the working directory.

Comment: Do I still have to fetch it from the central repository first?

Comment: I believe so. However, you will only have to do that once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor existing code, just create a feature branch and change all the stuff you need to change (even inside different directories). When you're done simply merge the changed stuff back into master or into another branch you're using.

To be honest I don't quite see the problem.

Comment: Pretend the code base is enormous, and branching becomes expensive in terms of network traffic, disk space, and time.

Comment: @AlexFeinman: The time taken to change branches should only be proportional to the size of the *changes* between two branches.

Comment: @GregHewgill this turns out not to be true. Git has to get the status of all the files, and that can take a long time if there are many files and/or a network involved. So it's proportional to both the size of the changes and the number of files, whichever is worse.

Comment: What exactly is many files in this case? I work on a considerably large codebase, but experience no problems whatsoever